# If statement for greater than or equal to 0 but not empty

Tags: php, operators

How can I do an if statement for greater than or equal to 0 but not empty? AND less than X?

At the moment if `$score` is empty then it considers it zero.

```
<?php if ($score >= 0 AND $score < $passmark) { ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "empty" in this case if 0 is not part of your "empty" set?

Answer (score 3):

Add a special case for zero:

```
if ($score === 0 || ($score > 0 && $score < $passmark))
```

`$score === 0` will fail for `false, 0.0, "", "0", [], null`; and these values will fail `$score > 0` check. If you want to extend your definition of empty to include any of these values add a special case just as you did for `0`.

Comment: You won m8 :) First type check / strict comparison, then value check, no string functions and string related stuff. Best approach.